# Navigate Component does not work with Routes location

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-transition-group

I am using react-transition-group and react-router-dom v6 to animate transitions. And it works correctly until I add the navigation component to the routes.

```
const Router: FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location)

  return (
    <TransitionGroup>
      <CSSTransition
        key={location.pathname}
        classNames={"page"}
        timeout={1000}
      >
        <div>
          <Routes location={location}>
            <Route path="/home" element={<div>Home</div>} />
            <Route path="/user" element={<div>User</div>} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={'/home'} />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </CSSTransition >
    </TransitionGroup >
  );
};
```

When I go to a url that does not match '/home' and '/user' the app starts to rerender and I get an error exceeding the maximum update depth.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9m5s.png)

Comment: Try `key={location.key}` on the `CSSTransition` component.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not solve the issue

Comment: Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?